# c# javascript select2 not working with combobox from Ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

i'm trying to make like here :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDltf.jpg)

if i click button [+], combobox will increasing but javascript/select2 not working with combobox that i get from Ajax.

code in view :

```
<input type="text" id="Jumlah" name="Jumlah" value="1" />
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        Pegawai<font class="text-danger">*</font>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1 text-right">
        1.
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-7">
        <input name='ComboboxPegawai_1' type="text" class="selectbox-o" style="width: 100%" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <a class="btn btn-default" onclick="TambahPgw()">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="FormPegawai">

</div>
```

and the script :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('.selectbox-o').select2({
          minimumInputLength: 0,
          ajax: {
               url: '@Url.Action("SearchPegawai", "Pegawai")',
               type: "post",
               dataType: 'json',
               data: function (term, page) {
                   return {
                      q: term
                   };
               },
               results: function (data, page) {
                    return { results: data };
                 }
              }
            });
        });


//this function for calling ajax to get new combobox

    function TambahPgw() {
        var x = parseInt($('#Jumlah').val());
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                Jumlah: $('#Jumlah').val()
            },
            url: "/Coba/AjaxTambahPegawai/",
            success: function (data) {
                $("#FormPegawai").html($("#FormPegawai").html() + data);
                $('#Jumlah').val(x + 1);
            },
        });
    }
</script>
```

and in controller, ajax to return combobox :

```
public string AjaxTambahPegawai()
    {
        var Jumlah = Int32.Parse(Request["Jumlah"]) + 1;
        var form = "<div class='form-group'><div class='col-md-2'></div>" +
                   "<div class='col-md-1 text-right'>" + Jumlah + ".</div>" +
                   "<div class='col-md-7'>" +
                        "<input name='ComboboxPegawai_" + Jumlah + "' type='text' class='selectbox-o' style='width: 100%' />" +
                   "</div></div>";

        return form;
    }
```

maybe javascript must be loaded again, but how?
i have tried to make a function for select2 and put on ajax -> success: function (data) { //functionselect2 }

but if i have selected on first combobox and i click button [+], the selected was lost because combobox reload again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After to put the html to the DOM you need to initialize the new input with select2.

```
$(".selectbox-o:last").select2(<options here!>);
```

But i think this isn't the best solution... why you pass html data from the controller instead of load a view?

NS

Comment: that's working! thank you for your help :D i think if using ajax to load a view is more difficult.. do you have other solution?

Comment: Hi, i think you could use a partial view with the html portion you needed and then using your controller to load that view. Try to search for "load partial view from controller", and you find some posts here in stackoverflow and this post may help  you too http://blog.iteedee.com/2014/04/using-asp-net-mvc-partial-view-controller-action/

Comment: i have problem again, if use $(".xxx:last").i cant access the first combobox, it can't be open. what's the other paramater except 'last'?

Comment: for the first you can use :first, please see this link https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 0):

In your ajax url you aren't referencing a file. Change it to something like:

```
/Coba/AjaxTambahPegawai.js
```

Then, change the way you call AjaxTambahPegawai to a function:

```
function AjaxTambahPegawai(){
//stuff
return form;
}
```

You may also want to separate the line:

```
var Jumlah = Int32.Parse(Request["Jumlah"]) + 1;
```

from the function call and instead pass Jumlah as a param to AjaxTambahPegawai.